# Using $.getJSON to fill a multi-select box

Tags: jquery, json, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am writing a simple test page, and am new to HTML and JQuery.  I'm using twitter bootstrap 2.04 for most of the formatting.  All I am wanting to do it use a JSON return to populate the list in a multi-select box when the page is loaded.  I have looked at tons of examples and tried several different way to get it to work, and the box remains blank.  As I said I'm somewhat new to the HTML and JQuery stuff so there is probably something simple that I am overlooking.  Here is a copy of my code.

```
        <select id="categorySelect" multiple="multiple"></select>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $.getJSON("https://myurl", function (response) {
                    $.each(response, function (categoryId, name) {
                        $('#categorySelect').append('<option id="' + categoryId + '">' + name + '<option/>');
                    });
                });
                });
        </script>
```

I really appreciate any help I can get.  Thanks!

Comment: what is inside the response object?  Are there any errors in the console?  Is this cross browser or on the same domain?

Comment: Check the console, what do you see!?

Comment: I'm building in VS2012 for Web.  The output widow from Debug mode just shows system services that have loaded.  There is nothing in the error list.

Comment: It is all contained within the same domain.